# when to use JMS (with websphere inbuilt messaging provider) vs a full fledged MQ product like ActiveMQ

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, ibm-mq

I understand JMS spec allows me to write MDBs. Then I can deploy them on an appserver like websphere or jboss (and they have inbuilt implementation of JMS provider which is Java EE compliant). The question is when to use a full fledged product like IBM WebSphere MQ or ACtiveMQ instead of using App server's inbuilt JMS provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a good reference to what you are asking, specific to IBM products but can be generalized to using an application server integrated messaging system vs a standalone messaging system - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1109_wallis/1109_wallis.html

Answer (score 1):

A built in JMS provider, such as WebSphere SI Bus, possibly others, are built for JMS messaging.

WebSphere MQ (MQSeries), ActiveMQ etc. have clients for multiple languages and are built for applications other than Application Server hosted applications to connect to it (C++, Java SE, Python, etc).

Say you want a local messaging server on the same physical server (or network?) as a non JavaEE application, you don't want to install a Java EE App Server, but want a stand alone messaging server instead (WebSphere MQ, Active MQ).

That said, ActiveMQ, for instance, is the messaging system inside Apache Geronimo. So there is overlapping here.

Then there is a whole discussion about management, clustering and security. Java EE messaging systems are pretty much optimized to follow the cluster layout of Java EE. In other deployment scenarios, the clustering might be optimal in other ways, such as cluster for different security zones. Also security models and management tools might be different in stand alone messagaing servers.